# Optimal orchestration of list of network calls and processing tasks in Java

Tags: java, asynchronous, stream

I have the following workflow:
There are `n` records that need to be retrieved over the network and subsequently `n` expensive computations that need to be done on each. Put in code, this would look like:

```
List<Integer> ids = {1,2,....n};
ids.forEach(id -> {
    Record r = RetrieveRecord(id); // Blocking IO
    ProcessRecord(r); // CPU Intensive
})
```

I would like to convert the blocking part into async so that the time is minimized with a single thread- essentially, by ensuring that record `i+1` is being retrieved when record `i` is being processed. So that the execution would look like:

```
Retrieve(1).start()
Retrieve(1).onEnd(() -> { start Retrieve(2), Process(1) })
Retrieve(2).onEnd(() -> { start Retrieve(3), Process(2) })
....
```

Now I can come up with the naive way to implement this with a `List<>` and `CompletableFuture`, but this would require me to handle the first record differently.

Is there a more elegant way of solving this with something like reactive streams? 
A solution that would maybe let me easily configure how many records `Process()` can trail behind `Retreive()`?

Comment: RetrieveRecord is a blocking operation. It always blocks some thread. If you move it to a single thread, then this thread would be execute all the retrievings sequentially and the time would be maximized, not minimized.

Comment: I already have a non blocking implementation of Retrieve() which returns a CompletableFuture. What I am trying to achieve here is a (strictly) bounded prefetch of next `k` records (k=1 in this case). Basically I dont want all 100 RetrieveRecords to be triggered in the start, neither do I want to wait till Process(i) is complete before starting Retreive(i+1). Basically Retrieve(i+k) should be happening over the wire while Process(i)  is running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I finally came up with that seems to get the job done:

```
Flowable.just(1,2,3,4,5,6) // Completes in 1 + 6 * 3 = 19 secs
    .concatMapEager(v->
            Flowable.just(v)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .map(  e->{
                System.out.println(getElapsed("Req " + e + " started");
                Thread.sleep(1000); // Network: 1 sec
                System.out.println(getElapsed("Req " + e + " done");
                return e;
            }, requestsOnWire, 1) // requestsOnWire = K = 2
           .blockingSubscribe(new DisposableSubscriber<Integer>() {
        @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            request(1);
        }
        @Override
        public void onNext(Integer s) {
            request(1);
            System.out.println("Proc " + s + " started");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000); // Compute: 3 secs
                System.out.println("Proc " + s + " done");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable t) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onComplete() {

        }
    });
```

Below is the execution order. Note that at any given point of time, there are 1 record being processed, at most 2 requests on wire and at most 2 unprocessed records in memory (Process trails behind by K=2) records:

```
 0 secs: Req 1 started
       : Req 2 started
 1 secs: Req 2 done
       : Req 1 done
       : Proc 1 started
       : Req 3 started
       : Req 4 started
 2 secs: Req 3 done
       : Req 4 done
 4 secs: Proc 1 done
       : Proc 2 started
       : Req 5 started
 5 secs: Req 5 done
 7 secs: Proc 2 done
       : Proc 3 started
       : Req 6 started
 8 secs: Req 6 done
10 secs: Proc 3 done
       : Proc 4 started
13 secs: Proc 4 done
       : Proc 5 started
16 secs: Proc 5 done
       : Proc 6 started
19 secs: Proc 6 done
```

Hope there are no anti-patterns/pitfalls here.

Comment: Note that increasing concurrency K is not beneficial in this example, but in scenarios where network takes longer than processing, increasing K speeds up the process

Answer (score 1):

So you have N tasks and want to run them in parallel but no more than K tasks simultaneously. Most natural way is to have a task generator and a permission counter with K permissions initially. Task generator creates K tasks and waits for more permissions. Each permission is owned by some task and is returned when the task ends. Standard permission counter in Java is class `java.util.concurrent.Semaphore`:

```
List<Integer> ids = {1,2,....n};
Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(K);
ids.forEach(id -> {
    sem.aquire();
    CompletableFuture<Data> fut = Retrieve(id);
    fut.thenRun(sem::release);
    fut.thenAcceptAsync(this::ProcessRecord, someExecutor);
})
```

Since the task generator occupies only one thread, there is little sense to make it asynchronous. If, however, you don't want to use a dedicated thread for task generator and want to implement asynchronous solution, then the main question is what class can play the role of asynchronous permission counter. You have 3 options:

- use implicit asynchronous permission counter which is a part of reactive streams, found in RxJava, project Reactor etc.
- use explicit asynchronous semaphore `org.df4j.core.boundconnector.permitstream.Semafor` included in my asynchronous library [df4j](https://github.com/akaigoro/df4j)
- make it yourself

Comment: Great! Could you give an example/link to the "implicit asynchronous permission counter" in RxJava? I tried a lot to find how to do this with RxJava since my project already has a dependency on this

Comment: Learn how to use backpressure in RxJava. Backpressure limits the number of items in a message queue, and you need to limit the number of asynchronous tasks. Map tasks to messages somehow.

Comment: But backpressure in RxJava has either "discard", "buffer" or "latest" strategy, which does not seem to fit my needs

Comment: I am not a specialist in RxJava, but I think strategy.BUFFER is ok for you, as it does not drops items. Task generator is implemented as an Observable, pushing tasks into a reactive stream and waiting when the stream is able to accept next task. The most tricky part is an Observer on the other end of the stream. It should take the next task and asynchronously wait when it is complete. Then start ProcessRecord() and take the next task.

Comment: I mostly get stuck with how to provide "k" (like in your snippet) when implementing with RxJava. All my attempts ended up with things working like k = 0 or k = N

Comment: find an example where subscriber calls method "request(n)". Initially it should call request(K) and then, after each task end, request(1).

Comment: I came up with version that works partially for k=1 (posted as solution). Maybe there's a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Solution using df4j, with explicit asynchronous semaphore:

```
import org.df4j.core.boundconnector.permitstream.Semafor;
import org.df4j.core.tasknode.Action;
import org.df4j.core.tasknode.messagestream.Actor;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;

public class AsyncSemaDemo extends Actor {
    List<Integer> ids = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    Semafor sema = new Semafor(this, 2);
    Iterator<Integer> iter = ids.iterator();
    int tick = 100; // millis
    CountDownLatch done = new CountDownLatch(ids.size());
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    private void printClock(String s) {
        long ticks = (System.currentTimeMillis() - start)/tick;
        System.out.println(Long.toString(ticks) + " " + s);
    }

    CompletableFuture<Integer> Retrieve(Integer e) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            printClock("Req " + e + " started");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(tick); // Network
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
            printClock(" Req " + e + " done");
            return e;
        }, executor);
    }

    void ProcessRecord(Integer s) {
        printClock(" Proc " + s + " started");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(tick*2); // Compute
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }
        printClock("  Proc " + s + " done");
    }

    @Action
    public void act() {
        if (iter.hasNext()) {
            CompletableFuture<Integer> fut = Retrieve(iter.next());
            fut.thenRun(sema::release);
            fut.thenAcceptAsync(this::ProcessRecord,  executor)
            .thenRun(done::countDown);
        } else {
            super.stop();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        AsyncSemaDemo asyncSemaDemo = new AsyncSemaDemo();
        asyncSemaDemo.start(ForkJoinPool.commonPool());
        asyncSemaDemo.done.await();
    }
}
```

its log should be:

```
0 Req 1 started
0 Req 2 started
1  Req 1 done
1  Proc 1 started
1 Req 3 started
1  Req 2 done
1  Proc 2 started
1 Req 4 started
2  Req 3 done
2  Proc 3 started
2 Req 5 started
2  Req 4 done
2  Proc 4 started
3   Proc 1 done
3  Req 5 done
3  Proc 5 started
3   Proc 2 done
4   Proc 3 done
4   Proc 4 done
5   Proc 5 done
```

Note how this solution is close to my previous answer with standard  `java.util.concurrent.Semaphore.`

Comment: This is spawns up k separate instances of Process() as well. I was looking at having only 1 Process() happening at any given point of time, while k requests  for future records are in the air. I was able to acheive this with flatMap and concatMap methods: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#parallel-processing

Comment: why do you think it spawns new Processes? It does not. Process is not even mentioned in the program.

Comment: I meant Proc 1 and Proc 2 are started together here. I understand that in most scenarious you would want this. But I did not want my workflow to be compute intensive, hence restricting Proc 1 and Proc 2 to be running in parallel. Plus it seems nice to use RxJava and not end up managing semaphores yourself

Comment: For N records, total time in my approach would be `Treq/K * N + K*Tproc` whereas yours would be
`Treq/K * N + Tproc` (faster, but at the expense of more CPU tasks in parallel)

Comment: if you want to run ProcessRecord() sequentially, just submit them to a dedicated single-threaded of serial executor.

Comment: Yeah. But I found that in cases where you can afford parallelism with compute tasks as well, RxJava makes it super easy to just chain another concatMap with a different concurrency. Intuitively, the Network to Compute concurrency ratio should be the inverse of Network to Compute processing time ratios so that there are no bursts in CPU utilization without compromising much on the throughput. Chaining syntax seems to be cleaner than maintaining that many semaphores, but they both work equally well