# Complete all tasks, but no more K tasks at the same time via Project Reactor

Tags: java, project-reactor

I'm beginner in `Project Reactor` and think it's pretty easy, but I can't find the solution.
I have `N` expensive tasks to do, and I want to implement something like `Bounded Semaphore` in Java (do not request next element until current count of running task less than `K`).
Shortly: complete all tasks, but no more `K` tasks at the same time

```
Flux.range(1, 100)
    .parallel()
    .limit(K) // Something like this
    .doOnNext(i -> expensiveWork(i))
    .subscribe()
```

Found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53448313/optimal-orchestration-of-list-of-network-calls-and-processing-tasks-in-java) on SO, but it's not for `Reactor`. But the meaning is the same. Please, help.

Close to my real case:

```
httpClient.getMainPageAsMono()
    .flatMapMany(html -> {
        Flux.fromIterable(getLinksFromPage(it));
    })
    .parallel(k)
    .runOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
    .flatMap(link -> {
        // ON THIS PART IT EXECUTES ALL LINKS AT THE SAME TIME
        // INSTEAD OF MAKING THROATTLE
        client.getAnotherPageByLink(link);
    })
    .....
    .subscribe()
```

That is, if the `getLinksFromPage(it)` function returns `1000` links, each next link will not be taken until `client.getAnotherPageByLink(link)` does it not finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using just `.parallel()` will give you a `ParallelFlux`, but in order to tell the resulting `ParallelFlux` where to run each rail (and, by extension, to run rails in parallel) you have to use `.runOn(Scheduler scheduler)`.

So we should use `.parallel(int parallelism)` with `.runOn(Scheduler scheduler)`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    int k = 3;        

    Flux.range(1, 100)
            .parallel(k)  // k rails
            .runOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic()) // the rails will run on this scheduler
            .doOnNext(i -> expensiveWork(i))
            .subscribe();

    Thread.currentThread().join(); // Just so program won't finish
}

private static void expensiveWork(Integer i) {
    Instant start = Instant.now();
    while (Duration.between(start, Instant.now()).getSeconds() < 5) ;
    System.out.println(Instant.now()+" - "+i+" - Done expensive work");
}
```

Output:

```
2021-06-12T13:46:58.445Z - 3 - Done expensive work
2021-06-12T13:46:58.445Z - 1 - Done expensive work
2021-06-12T13:46:58.445Z - 2 - Done expensive work
2021-06-12T13:47:03.453Z - 5 - Done expensive work
2021-06-12T13:47:03.453Z - 6 - Done expensive work
2021-06-12T13:47:03.453Z - 4 - Done expensive work
2021-06-12T13:47:08.453Z - 8 - Done expensive work
2021-06-12T13:47:08.453Z - 7 - Done expensive work
2021-06-12T13:47:08.453Z - 9 - Done expensive work
...
```

As you can see, we limited the number of tasks that are executed in parallel to `k`.

Comment: Instead of sleeping for a long time, let's use Thread.currentThread().join();

Comment: Welcome. And I guess you forgot the "throws Exception" in main method definition. But it is a detail :)

Comment: Thanks very much. This example seems to work, but not for my real case. Strange, perhaps the details play a big role. Maybe I have incorrect using `flatMapMany`. I edited the question, can you see it?

Comment: After spending a lot of time, I seem to have come to what I wanted with your help. The problem was using `flatMap` with `delayElements`. For some reasons, during the `delay`, other elements began to be emitted, without waiting for the end of the first. When I changed `flatMap` to `concatMap` it worked. I need to learn more about the difference between these methods. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

What about this solution? I removed parallel from Flux, in order to bufferize 10 elements. Each elements can be then handled in parallel

```
public static final void main(String... args) {

     Flux.range(1, 1000)
            .buffer(10)
            .doOnNext(grp -> grp.parallelStream().forEach(p -> System.out.println(Instant.now() + " : " + p)))
            .doOnNext(grp -> sleep(1000)) // Wait for 1 second to see how the algorithm is working
            .doOnNext(grp -> System.out.println("####")) 
            .subscribe();
}

private static void sleep(int millis) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(millis);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
2021-06-12T14:16:23.760298200Z : 8
2021-06-12T14:16:23.760298200Z : 4
2021-06-12T14:16:23.760298200Z : 10
2021-06-12T14:16:23.760298200Z : 1
2021-06-12T14:16:23.760298200Z : 3
2021-06-12T14:16:23.760298200Z : 5
2021-06-12T14:16:23.760298200Z : 7
2021-06-12T14:16:23.760298200Z : 2
2021-06-12T14:16:23.760298200Z : 6
2021-06-12T14:16:23.760298200Z : 9
####
2021-06-12T14:16:24.784628Z : 17
2021-06-12T14:16:24.784628Z : 16
2021-06-12T14:16:24.784628Z : 20
2021-06-12T14:16:24.784628Z : 14
2021-06-12T14:16:24.784628Z : 11
2021-06-12T14:16:24.784628Z : 13
2021-06-12T14:16:24.784628Z : 18
2021-06-12T14:16:24.784628Z : 19
2021-06-12T14:16:24.784628Z : 12
2021-06-12T14:16:24.785801500Z : 15
```

As you can see, each 10 elements are processed by group in parallel within each second

Comment: Thanks, but `take` takes a specific number of elements (10 for your example), it will not execute other (111 -200 element will be skipped).  This is not what I am trying to do. I need to complete all tasks, but no more K tasks at the same time.

Comment: I posted another way of solution if you want to have a look

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily accomplished without parallel using an overloaded version of `flatMap` where you can specify concurrency:

[`flatMap(Function<? super T,? extends Publisher<? extends V>> mapper, int concurrency)`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-int-)

```java
httpClient.getMainPageAsMono()
    .flatMapMany(html -> {
        Flux.fromIterable(getLinksFromPage(it));
    })
    .flatMap(link -> client.getAnotherPageByLink(link), k)
    .....
    .subscribe()
```

Based on the code, this operation is not expensive in terms of CPU, rather in terms of IO, so using `ParallelFlux` is not necessary.